# Implement jwt-permissions on NodeJS - UnauthorizedError

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, token

I am new to the use of Nodejs but I confess that I am loving, I am using tokens Jwt for authentication of users, simple thing, they log and win a token. but I want to put permissions on the routes, I've been reading about express-jwt-permissions, but using it in my application I'm getting the following error at POSTMAN: UnauthorizedError: user object "user" was not found. Check your configuration.

customerRoutes.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var guard = require('express-jwt-permissions')()
const customerController = require('../controllers/customerController');




  function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  // Check if bearer is undefined
  if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
  // Split at the space
   const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
   // Get token from array
   const bearerToken = bearer[1];
     // Set the token
    req.token = bearerToken;
    // Next middleware
   next();
   } else {
   // Forbidden
   res.sendStatus(403);
  }

  }

   router.post('/posts',verifyToken,guard.check('admin'),
   customerController.posts);

   module.exports = router;
```

this is how my token looks : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6WyJhZG1pbiJdLCJpYXQiOjE1Mzc0MDg0NzMsImV4cCI6MTUzNzQ0ODQ3M30.8l1vezWWz3Gmb5M3N0DgsmCl-nZHK2c3GP-dKzYDLRU

Comment: There is no user field in your token.
'{"permissions":["admin"],"iat":1537408473,"exp":1537448473}'

Comment: i try this token , but i receive the same error : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7InBlcm1pc3Npb25zIjpbInVzZXIiLCJhZG1pbiJdfSwiaWF0IjoxNTM3NDA5MjY2LCJleHAiOjE1Mzc0NDkyNjZ9.fcwnIwm1Inup5M_d_N67230qfOulNBObinwx-z6LrtA

Comment: Your token should use split('.'), you can print bearer[1], the theory should be 'eyJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6WyJhZG1pbiJdLCJpYXQiOjE1Mzc0MDg0NzMsImV4cCI6MTUzNzQ0ODQ3M30', then check, decoding steps I did not see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `express-jwt-permissions`

> This middleware assumes you already have a JWT authentication middleware such as express-jwt.

And then tracing towards `express-jwt` documentation, with the first example:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

app.get('/protected',
  jwt({secret: 'shhhhhhared-secret'}),
  function(req, res) {
    if (!req.user.admin) return res.sendStatus(401);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

And associate with your encountered error, it's safe to say that `express-jwt-permissions` middleware is expecting a populated `req.user` field with the value of an object (then I actually checked their source code https://github.com/MichielDeMey/express-jwt-permissions/blob/master/index.js#L11 and proves that it is the case).

So my suggestion would be either use `express-jwt` which does the work for you and is known to work with `express-jwt-permissions`, or populate a `req.user` object within your `verifyToken` middleware by yourself (requires decoding of the JWT), something like:

```
// decode JWT
// get decoded token.permissions
req.user = {
  permissions: token.permissions
};
```

Before invoking `next()` to the next middleware.

Note that you can also tweak `express-jwt-permissions` to expect a different field than `user` (but still need to live in the `req` namespace of express middleware life-cycle), as well as a different name than `permissions` field inside the token payload. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-permissions#configuration for details. But either way, the bottom line is you'll need to decode the token first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sure I'll be implementing the use of express-jwt in my application.

Comment: @JairBolsonaro have fun!